# how can I use the output of a sample to use in another sample?

Tags: r

In my problem for example, when a user flips a coin, depending on the flip, they can roll a d4 die, or a d6. (so heads can equal d6 and tails can equal d4 so to speak).  From there I need to use Monte Carlo simulation to find the expected roll (the answer is 3 but we need to write the code for it).

```
roll <- function(){
  
  d4 <- sample(1:4,1)
  d6 <- sample(1:6,1)
  
  dice <- sample(c(d4, d6),1)
  coin <- sample(c("H","T"),1)
  
  sum(which(coin == "H") & which(dice == d4))
  
}

mean(replicate(10000, roll()))
```

I could use a little to nudge to the right direction

Comment: You are going to tell your instructor you got help on Stack Overflow, right?

Comment: Yeah, the class is probability and statistics, and not due untill Tuesday, I have been working on the problems during the weekend and got stuck on this one in particular.

I got stuck on mostly on the fact I cant use if statements or loops (I should have stated that in the problem, my apologies)

Comment: but `ifelse()` is allowed ... ?  (I can appreciate why instructors put constraints on solutions, but sometimes it seems a bit silly; you could do something like `r <- sample(0:1,1); r*sample(4,1) + (1-r)*sample(6,1)` ....)  Do you have any clues about what direction they intended you to go when they forbade `if` statements ... ?

Comment: Ya I emailed him about it and said the coin isnt really needed  and the quetion just has awkward wording.  All I needed was the die vector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sum(which(coin == "H") & which(dice == d4))` is not selecting the dice based on the coin. Use something like `res <- ifelse(coin == "H", d6, d4)` to select which dice roll you want to use based on the coin flip.

This is giving an output of ~3:

```
roll <- function(){
  
  d4 <- sample(1:4,1)
  d6 <- sample(1:6,1)
  
  dice <- sample(c(d4, d6),1)
  coin <- sample(c("H","T"),1)
  
  res <- ifelse(coin == "H", d6, d4)
  return(res)
}

mean(replicate(10000, roll()))
```

Comment: `ifelse()` is OK but `if` is probably preferable if you're really only going to be testing a scalar expression ...

Comment: There are lots of ways of doing it, and your approach is probably what I would go with. I was just trying to make minimal changes to the original code.

Comment: fair enough. `res <- if (coin=="H") d6 else d4` works nicely but is (I think) confusing to newbies.

Answer (score 4):

I think you want something along the lines of

```
coin <- sample(c("H","T"),1)
if (coin=="H") {
   return(sample(1:4,1))
} else {
   return(sample(1:6,1))
}
```

You don't really need the `else` clause to be stated explicitly (because the code will only get past the `if` statement if `coin != "H"`).

This could be done more compactly, at the cost of legibility (you don't need to store the results in `coin` temporarily, especially since you're only using that piece of information once). Or it could be done *less* compactly (and a little more like your original code) by storing `d4` and `d6` and then `if (coin=="H") { return(d4) } else { return(d6) }`.

It's very tempting to start code-golfing (e.g. `sample(sample(c(4,6),1),1)`) ... or `r <- sample(0:1,1); r*sample(4,1) + (1-r)*sample(6,1)` or ...